# Vanilla ASP.NET Core project has 2 second delay for every request

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

If I open Visual Studio 2019 (16.5.4) and create a new ASP.NET Core Web Application and select the Angular template then run the application in Chrome with dev tools open I see that every single request takes a minimum of 2 seconds to complete:

[image]

What is going on there? Why is 2 seconds delay being added to every request?

Comment: If you're running from within VS, you're probably running Angular in development mode. The site doesn't compile until the first request, which is the delay you're seeing. If you refresh the page, or run the application in release mode (with angular pre-published), you should not see this